# Android DatePickerDialog mask calendar

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I'm currently fighting with Android DatePickerDialog, as I want to mask calendar and display only 3 fields (day, month, year), as a compact and much more simple alternative as I ask a birthdate.

```
public void addCalendar(){
    final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.FRANCE);

            _birthdateText.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
        }

    };

    _birthdateText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(SignupActivity.this, date, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            dpd.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);
            //dpd.getDatePicker().setSpinnersShown(true);
            dpd.setTitle(getString(R.string.birthdate_picker_title));
            dpd.show();
        }
    });
}
```

I have the impression that setCalendarViewShown(false) is not considered.

Comment: have you seen this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680221/android-remove-calendarview-from-datepickerdialogfragment

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to inflate through a layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner">
    </DatePicker>
</LinearLayout>
```

This pretty much works even in Lollipop, hides Calendar.

Comment: Thanks, how can I mask this and made that appears when I'm clicking on a EditText, filling it with the result of the dialog ?

Comment: You can override `onFocus` of `EditText` and display `DatePicker`. and in your `setPositiveButton` of `DatePicker` you can set the `EditText` value.